# Easy_install or pip install error : [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)]

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

On my centos server, all of sudden I received SSL verify failed message whenever trying to install the new package.

Can someone help me on this ?

On New Machine:

```
easy_install-2.7 pip Searching for pip Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ Best match: pip 10.0.1 Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/e8/2340d46ecadb1692a1e455f13f75e596d4eab3d11a57446f08259dee8f02/pip-10.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=f2bd08e0cd1b06e10218feaf6fef299f473ba706582eb3bd9d52203fdbd7ee68 error: Download error for https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/e8/2340d46ecadb1692a1e455f13f75e596d4eab3d11a57446f08259dee8f02/pip-10.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=f2bd08e0cd1b06e10218feaf6fef299f473ba706582eb3bd9d52203fdbd7ee68: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)
```

Existing server where I installed lots of python modules using pip earlier, but now I receiving ssl verification error

```
# pip install certifi Collecting certifi   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)': /packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)': /packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)': /packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)': /packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),)': /packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),))
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is caused by https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1543 which is not sorted yet.

The only workaround I know is to avoid using a proxy, or at least use one that does not rewrite SSL certificates.

Do not forget to comment on that issue to confirm it affects you too.